# Update Google Domain Shared Contact Photo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-people-api

I am using Google Apps Script to access Domain Shared Contacts and update contact information using the People API.

I am able to successfully add a contact photo to the authorised users contact using:

```
var photoClass = {photoBytes: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(testIDPhotoBlob.getBytes()),
personFields:'photos'};
var testId = 'people/c12345678901234'
var updatePhoto = People.People.updateContactPhoto(photoClass,testId);
```

This successfully updates the contacts photo. Note that the contact is a users contact and beings with a 'people/c'.

If I use the same method to update a domain shared contact:

```
var photoClass = {photoBytes: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(testIDPhotoBlob.getBytes()),
personFields:'photos'};
var testId = 'people/d12345678901234'
var updatePhoto = People.People.updateContactPhoto(photoClass,testId);
```

Note the contact Id begins with a 'person/d'. This returns the error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.updateContactPhoto failed with error: Resource name "people/d12345678901234" is not a valid contact person resource.
```

The domain contact does exist as:

```
var testPersonSearch = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople({query:'Domain Contact Name',readMask:findFields,sources:['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT']});

Returns:
{ people: 
   [ { organizations: [Object],
       names: [Object],
       phoneNumbers: [Object],
       emailAddresses: [Object],
       etag: '%xxxxxx/yyyyyyy',
       resourceName: 'people/d12345678901234"' } ],
  totalSize: 1 }
```

I understand that the old API /m8/feeds did not have this feature properly implemented.

If I use the following code for the SharedContactsAPI:

```
var contact = SharedContactsApp.getContactById('hexadecimalValueofContact');
console.log(contact.hasProfilePicture()); 
returns false as contact is valid but no image exists....
console.log(contact.setProfilePicture(testIDPhotoBlob));
returns null
```

Also by using the REST API directly using UrlFetchApp.fetch etc has a similar result stating the contact cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

### For shared contacts you need to use the [Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts)

Mind:

> The Shared Contacts API is intended only for external contacts. Using this API to create contact information for domain users or groups can result in duplicate contact information for those users and groups, which may lead to unexpected behavior.

To implement the `Shared Contacts API` with Apps Script, you can use the open source [SharedContactsApp](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/shared-contacts) library. The documentation provides you an instruction and samples of how to use it.

Comment: I am afraid the Shared Contacts API uses the old /m8/feeds and does not work.

Comment: See [here](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement). It says: "the Domain Shared Contacts API is not affected by these changes"

Comment: Hello - the ShareContactsAPI and /m8/feeds/ are still in use for domain shared contacts even after the Contacts API sunset, the point is the /m8/feeds and SharedContactsAPI have not yet fixed photos for domain shared contacts even though it was first written in 2013 and updated in 2015!